# How to specify two different login forms for two different URLs in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a relatively complex spring security configuration, as shown below. What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

requests to `/passport/**` will be authenticated, with an alternative `formLogin()` `("/passport/login")`. This is different to the default formLogin, which resolves on `("/login")`

Both forms will use the same authentication mechanism (or very similar behind the scenes).

At the moment, requests to `/passport/123` etc. are somehow 'open' and unauthenticated, whereas they need to redirect to `/passport/login` can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or how to best achieve this?

Many of the docs I've read online suggest going for **two different configuration classes**, whereas I have one but the logic for logging in will be similar. Given that there's also a fair amount of other bits going on that will need replicated, if at all possible, I'd like to have just one config.

```
 http

     .antMatcher( "/passport/**" )
     .authorizeRequests().and()
        .formLogin().loginPage( "/passport/login" )
        .successHandler( authSuccessHandler() )
        .failureHandler( authFailureHandler() )
     .and()
      .antMatcher( "/**" )
         .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers( HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/" ).permitAll()
           .antMatchers( HttpMethod.GET, "/app/**" ).permitAll()
           .antMatchers( LOGIN_DESTINATION + "**" ).permitAll()
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
           .oauth2Login()
              .loginPage( LOGIN_DESTINATION )
              .authorizationEndpoint()
                  .baseUri( "/oauth2/authorize" )
                  .authorizationRequestRepository( cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() )
                  .and()
              .redirectionEndpoint()
                  .baseUri( "/oauth2/callback/*" )
                  .and()
              .userInfoEndpoint()
                  .userService( customOAuth2UserService )
                  .and()
           .successHandler( oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler )
           .failureHandler( oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler )
           .and()
       .formLogin()
          .loginPage( "/login" )
          .successHandler( authSuccessHandler() )
          .failureHandler( authFailureHandler() )
          .and()
      .logout()
         .logoutUrl( "/logout" )
         .logoutSuccessUrl( "/" )
         .deleteCookies( "cookieLogin" )
         .logoutSuccessHandler( ( httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication ) -> {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
         } )
      .and()
      .rememberMe()
         .rememberMeServices( new RememberMeServices( loginService, tokenService ) )
         .key( TokenService.HASH_SECRET )
         .and()

.csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository( new CsrfTokenRepository( tokenService ) )
            .and()



      .sessionManagement()
         .sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS )

      .and()
         .addFilterBefore( new TokenFilter( tokenService, sessionManager ), CsrfFilter.class );
```

Comment: `/passport**` doesn't match your urls. It should be `/passport/**` to match.

Comment: @M.Deinum - typo on my part whilst bringing the code through to Stackoverflow. had to anonymise some bits code actually running did have the forward slash

Comment: You haven't actually protected the `/passport` urls. You only defined a login-page, hence security will not kick in.

Comment: @M.Deinum super thanks!... just .antMatchers( "/passport/**").denyAll() ? My assumption was  .anyRequest().authenticated() would do it.

Comment: if you `denyAll` noone is allowed access. You want an `anyRequest().authenticated()` inside the `antMatcher(/passport/**)`. I fyou don't there are no security rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same URL, but have a query parameter such as: `loginType`, which can have the value `PASSPORT` or `DEFAULT`, and default it to `DEFAULT` when it's not present.

Read this query parameter in your `Controller` and return a different view, or return the same view, with state which determines how the page should be customized for the correct `loginType`. A similar approach is used when somebody tries to login and fails, an old school servlet application would add a `error=true` and display an error message that the user failed to Authenticate.